# Maven multi-module project only deploy -SNAPSHOT modules in mvn deploy

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

- I have a snapshot and a release repository defined in the pom.xml of all modules
- The modules in my project may be developed and updated independently, i.e. one may be updated (and hence be -SNAPSHOT) during development whereas all others are untouched with release versions
- My release nexus repository prevents redeployment
- Running mvn deploy will successfully deploy -SNAPSHOT projects to the snapshot repository as required but when it tries to reploy one of the unchanged modules the build fails because that module is already in the release repository
- I do not want releases to be redeployable - once a release is deployed it is final

Is there a way to run "mvn deploy" such that all snapshot bundles do get deployed but release modules are skipped?